# Saving one-to-many relationship in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

```
public Master Add(Master request)
{
    request.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    // master
    Context.Entry(request).State = EntityState.Added;
    // details
    if (request.Details != null && request.Details?.Count != 0)
    {
        request.Details.ForEach(x => Context.Entry(x).State = EntityState.Added);    
    }
    Context.SaveChanges();
    return request;
}
```

I am trying to insert master and list of details with relation one to many  using ef core,
but an exception has been thrown in this line inside foreach.

instance of entity type cannot be tracked because another instance with same key value is tracked

How could i do it ?

Thanks

Comment: if Details List has one item, data saved  ...  if more than one item the exception thrown : The instance of entity type 'Details' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

Comment: I suggest you add `Master` and `Details` to the database separately.

Comment: I am new to ef core, how could i do it ?   --- there are relationship between master and details (one to many)

Comment: you should change your strategy. first, you add a `master` entity to Db. then create a new view or page and add `details` one by one! you should define new method like `public void AddDetail(Details entity) {}`

Answer (score 0):

if you add the master ,entity framework automatically will add its children

```
public Master Add(Master request)
{
    request.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    // master
    Context.Entry(request).State = EntityState.Added;
    Context.SaveChanges();
    return request;
}
```

Comment: i did but only added the master without any details   ...  the master model has property List<Details> and Details model has property of Master  ...  and here my configuration   :     builder.HasMany(x => x.Details).WithOne(x => x.Master).HasForeignKey(x => x.Id).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

Comment: did you check that this one to many relationship  have recognized by the entity frame work in the migration file

Comment: did you try to add the master by writing 
context.masters.add(master);

Comment: adding  the master only adds the master row with no any details

Answer (score 0):

the problem was in the Details table,  it had just a foreign key to Master table with no any primary key (id) .. so i get the exception

```
The instance of entity type 'Details' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked.
```

after adding a primary key to it it works fine.